# UITableView on DetailView of SplitView doesn't load it's data

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

Using Xcode 4.3.1, ipad app for iOS 5.1, no core-data

On my storyboard I have a master-detail project. The master obviously has a TableView, and that works fine: by selecting an item in the master tableview my detail data is set in the detail view controller by the template code call setDetailItem (which I call from 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'). That works fine.

My DetailView/Scene contains (another) UITableView (amongst other, also some TextFields etc.)
This UITAbleView's datasource and delegate are connected to the detail view controller.
In the detail viewcontroller's interface file I adde the protocols UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate (next to the pre-configured UISplitViewControllerDelegate).

I implemented the methods numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath, didSelectRowAtIndexPath methods in the detail view controller.

However, these are only called when the master tableview's list is build up, not when I select an item in the master list/tableview. When I select an item in the master list/tableview the detail data get's set in the detail viewcontroller, but for instance the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' in the detail controller is never called, and the detail TableView is not updated/initialised. (The textfield in the detail view however is loaded with the correct data).

I guess I am missing something. Do I have to give the tableview a kick at the point I prepared it's data? And if so, how...? The tableview itself is not connected to an outlet or action, should it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom delegate (one-to-one communication) from RootView to Detailview.
Like the following,
Implement the Delegate in RootView,

```
@protocol RootViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didchangeSelectionInRootViewList:(id)toItem;

@end
```

And call the delegate when needed as (in your case on table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath),

```
//a delegete need in caes of splitview to refresh the detailview.
-(void)callDelegate:(id)sender  {
    if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didchangeSelectionInRootViewList:)])    {
        [self.delegate didchangeSelectionInRootViewList:sender];
    }
}
```

And don't forgot to set the delegate in Rootview as detailview while creating splitview controller.

And also catch the delegate in Detailview and reload the TableView with sufficient data to load.

thanks,

Naveen Shan